# iOS - How to present large number of views with the same layout?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Here is what I'd like to achieve:
1) present a fairly large number of screens (about a dozen) with identical layouts but different info. (Basically a set of info pages for different events - dynamically set)
2) the user should be able to use swipe to move between the pages, and the transitions should be animated
3) I'd prefer to manage all the data from a single view controller.

What would be the optimal way to achieve this? I was thinking of keeping only two views in memory, dynamically updating the content of the currently invisible view when the user swipes, and then animating from one view to the other. Should I use one of the container view controllers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should look at using a UIPageViewController. It is a parent view controller that manages a group of child view controllers that each display a single page of content.

Each page would be an instance of the same class of content view controller that you create.

A page view controller uses a data source and a delegate much like a table view does.

There is an app in the Xcode docs called PhotoScroller that shows how to set up a page view controller using a swipe gesture to switch pages. It's  got a lot more complexity than you need in the view controllers that display photos (those photos are large tiled images and the photo view controllers have a bunch of code you can ignore that manages tiled images.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion, Duncan! It also led me to a decent tutorial on using UIPageViewController (http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/).

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably use a UITableView that has cells large enough to take up the whole screen.  That'll handle reusing the views (UITableViewCells) for you and you'll need to disable the tableview scrolling and implement paging when the user swipes.

Apply a rotation translation to the tableview's layer and then apply the inverse rotation translation to each of the cells if you want a horizontally-scrolling tableview.

Alternatively, I believe iCarousel will handle view reuse.

Comment: Ugh. What a hacked mess. Why put a table view through such contortions when UIPageViewController does everything the OP wants? UICollectionView isn't quite as tailor-made to the OPs question, but it would sure be a lot better than a table view with screen-sized cells and a rotated transform.